# using fbchat 1.9.7 to login to messenger and having problem with login

Tags: python

After login try, i get an error "fbchat._exception.FBchatUserError: Login failed. Check email/password. (Failed on url: https://m.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1)"

Login details are 100% correct, code worked yesterday, but today I get error mentioned above.
Can someone please help me with this?

```
from fbchat import Client
from fbchat.models import *

client = Client(email,password)
```

Comment: Yeah, I have same issue. It stopped working suddenly. It seems that facebook made changes to the login process. Where you able to fix it? I am still trying to find solution or change the library.

Comment: Cant fix it to this day

Comment: My FB bot is working, I did some changes, but at the end I sticked with the authetication using cookies.

Comment: @LukášMichalec Can you post it to github and provide me with link to repo? Would really appreciate it if you could.

Comment: Sure, I do not remember exactly what was I changing, but I can post those 3 key files that was modified with the sample how I run the script. I will put link to the Git as answer here.